# PDF viewer/editor

Tags: software-recommendation, adobe-acrobat

On Windows I use Adobe Acrobat. With that I can create, edit pdf's or just fill in documents. There are programs available for making/editing pdf but they don't work that well.

So I am hoping you know a good one that has similar functions as Acrobat. I would switch to Windows right now but my primary notebook is out for repair so I have to do it with my old notebook witch only has Ubuntu to try it out and learn a little bit more

Comment: Other good ressources: http://askubuntu.com/q/1529/81372 http://askubuntu.com/q/16652/81372

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem i have with these other questions is that it is for highlighting and adding comments and not editing. Or the programs don't work how they should. (which is a personal thing i guess.)

Comment: I understand that. In this case we usually advise you to comment on the existing questions/answers. You don't have enough reputation points to do so yet but opening a duplicate question is not the solution. [It crowds up the site and makes it more difficult for future users to find a good answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: [Here's another Q&A concerning PDF editors](http://askubuntu.com/q/228531/81372). (We should probably consolidate all of these into a single Q&A at one point. It's very easy to lose the overview.)

Comment: Seems like you have an idea of what you are looking for, did you check out [this](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf)?

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful?

Comment: All the answers were helpfull. I have tried different options and so far master pdf editor works best. And when i cant do something i switch to windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Master pdf editor you can find it in Ubuntu software centre.

Comment: So far this is the best. Not as good as Adobe Acrobat so i switch to windows sometimes but for ubuntu this is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

For creating, editing and printing PDFs, the default installed [Libreoffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) should be good at it, as it prints and edits anyway. If you want to edit PDFs after exporting them, select the following when exporting PDFs  from Libreoffice (use 'Export as PDF...' in the File menu):

[image]

This means that you can open the exported PDF in Libreoffice and edit it easily. You probably can't edit PDFs created by other software though.

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228531/what-pdf-editors-are-available-on-ubuntu?rq=1) for other software choices.

I don't use Adobe Acrobat so don't know if this is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was one of the first answers i found and tried. Yesterday i got a document (.pdf) from my local hospital which i have to fill in and send back to them. There are questions that i have to answer starting with "Name:___" and stuff like that. In Acrobat i click on the line and start typing. In Libreoffice i click on the line and start typing and instead of typing on the line the text appears under the line. In this case i print the document and fill it in but digital is supposed to be easier and faster.

Comment: You can usually press backspace and then edit the line so what you type in doesn't go under it - for that problem in particular, there is a question on that as well - http://askubuntu.com/questions/166875/create-fillable-or-editable-fields-in-a-pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can install adobe-acrobat using wine on ubuntu.

1. Install wine from the software centre or from the terminal using:

   sudo apt-get install wine
2. Download the version of adobe-acrobat you want from [their repositories](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat.html?promoid=JOPBV).
3. Extract the downloaded zip file and open the executable installer by right-clicking and choosing wine as the application to open.
4. This will open adobe acrobat's standard installer and you can install it as you install in on windows.
5. Now to open adobe acrobat, you will need to open it using the terminal as follows:

   ```
   wine <path/to/adobe/acrobat/application/exe>
   ```

   Replacing `<path/to/adobe/acrobat/application/exe>` with the path where adobe acrobat's exe is stored. In my case it is `$USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Adobe/Reader\ 11.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe`.
6. You can store this command as an alias in your `~/.bash_aliases` file to type just `adobe-acrobat` to execute this command.

**Note:** I have [a blog on this](http://thelittleican.blogspot.in/2013/10/how-to-highlight-pdfs-in-ubuntu.html), have a look for more details.

Comment: Well, that sure is a good thing that i can use acrobat in ubuntu. Wine is something like virtualbox for ubuntu? (does that mean i can install photoshop as well? (hate gimp)

Comment: No, wine is not like virtualbox; they are different- wine is used to run windows programs on linux and virtualbox is used to run windows itself as a virtual machine. I am not sure whether you can install and use photoshop using wine since I have not done it, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Its a compatibility layer [(not quite an emulator)](http://www.winehq.org/about/) -  a few versions of Photoshop may run under Wine, see [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17)